# I cant seem to insert a special character like “\” in a MySQL database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I cant seem to insert a special character like “\” in a MySQL database

here's my code

```
<?php
  $insert_data = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table_name (id, img) VALUES('', '<img title="\sum" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\sum" data-mce-src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\sum" data-mce-selected="1">')");
?>
```

Comment: `\\` is not a wildcard. Also it got special meaning: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php And finally, your onliner is invalid -> syntax errror.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `"` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP, you need to escape backslash (\) with another backslash like this `\\` inside a string

```
<?php
$insert_data = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table_name (id, img) VALUES('', '<img title="\\sum" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\sum" data-mce-src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\sum" data-mce-selected="1">')");
?>
```

Comment: sorry but this code does not work for me any other options or ways of doing this???

Comment: @fuzzybuddy Can you explain how does it not work for you? What is the stored data? What is the expected data?

Comment: Oh sorry the seem to have worked just a little bit of a twitch and it was working thanks :)